# Facebook: Check if post id exists on fb user wall using read_stream

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have an app on facebook that publishes stories on users wall. I am trying to prevent spamming users wall with the same story being published multiple times so this is what I did.

After a successful share I store the facebook Post id on my servers database. 
I am stuck at the part where I  have to check if the post id stored on my servers db exists on users wall before posting the story?

I requested publish_stream and read_stream!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/<post_id>?access_token=<users access token>`, if you get a "truthy" response back, the post exists, if you get a graph api error/exception, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: is there any way to get graph response in php boolean true false ?

Comment: you could write yourself a function to check for the existence of the post and have that function interpret the response and return a bool, but the graph api isn't going to return a bool for that

Comment: Yep I am going to use php json_decode and check array for created_time from graph, if doesn't exists publish again!

Thanks Jim

Comment: is this possible using batch request?